# Snake not eating food in the snake game in python

Tags: python, tkinter

When running the code, when the snake and food coordinates are equal, the food is supposed
to get deleted, the score should be incremented by 1, another square to be added to snake and new
food object to be created BUT even when the coordinated of snake object and food object are overlapping
the if statement in next_turn function doesnt works and the snake simply run over the food object
without anyone of the desired changes.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#Constants
GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SPEED = 50
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 2
SNAKE_COLOR = '#00FF00'
FOOD_COLOR = '#FF0000'
BG_COLOR = '#000000'



class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill = SNAKE_COLOR, tag = 'snake')
        self.squares.append(square)


class Food:

    def __init__(self):

        x = random.randint(0, ((GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1)*SPACE_SIZE)
        y = random.randint(0, ((GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1)*SPACE_SIZE)

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        self.some = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill = FOOD_COLOR, tag = 'foodtherealdeal')

def next_turn(snake, food):

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == 'up':
        y -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == 'down':
        y += SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == 'left':
        x -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == 'right':
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill = SNAKE_COLOR)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if [x, y] == food.coordinates :

        global score
    
        score += 1

        label.config(text=f'Score : {score}')

        canvas.delete('foodtherealdeal')

        food = Food()

    else:
        del snake.coordinates[-1]

        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

        del snake.squares[-1]

    window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)


def change_dir(new_dir):

    global direction

    if new_dir == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction = new_dir

    elif new_dir == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction = new_dir

    elif new_dir == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction = new_dir    

    elif new_dir == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction = new_dir

def check_collision():
    pass

def gameOver():
    pass


window = Tk()
window.title("Snake Game")
window.resizable(False, False)
score = 0
direction = 'down'

label = Label(window, text=f"Score : {score}", font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg = BG_COLOR, height = GAME_HEIGHT, width = GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()


window.update()

window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

#Controls
window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_dir('left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_dir('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_dir('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_dir('down'))

window.bind('A', lambda event: change_dir('left'))
window.bind('D', lambda event: change_dir('right'))
window.bind('W', lambda event: change_dir('up'))
window.bind('S', lambda event: change_dir('down'))

window.bind('a', lambda event: change_dir('left'))
window.bind('d', lambda event: change_dir('right'))
window.bind('w', lambda event: change_dir('up'))
window.bind('s', lambda event: change_dir('down'))

snake = Snake()

food = Food()

next_turn(snake, food)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: As @Tomerikoo suggested, you need to debug. Put a print(x,y,food.coordinates) before the if statement and verify the values. Even if they overlap each other on the screen, the coordinates may not be exactly equal. You are better off checking for collision within a certain range. Something like between x-5 and x+5, and also between y-5 and y+5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your food can spawn at any integer coordinate in your code. However, the snake only moves with multiples of `SPACE_SIZE`. The chance of a piece of food being initialized at such a point that the snake can actually reach it is 1/SPACE_SIZE**2 == 1/2500. Fixing this requires a subtle change of moving a some parentheses:

```py
def __init__(self):
    x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
    y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
```

This creates the food at coordinates that are multiples of `SPACE_SIZE` so that they are always reachable by the snake.

Alternatively, you could change the if statement to allow for some small difference in the coordinates, but this would be less true to the original game of snake.